# F5 BIG-IP Powershell/iControl - Query Current Connections at the Node Level

Tags: powershell, f5

I am working on Powershell scripts to do automated deployments to our servers behind our BIG-IP LTM.

I have simple scripts that use the iControl powershell cmdlets to disable and re-enable the nodes:

`Disable-F5.LTMNodeAddress -Node xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

These work quite well, however for this to become a truly automated process, what I need next is a way to query the Current Connections to the node as they bleed off so that my automation doesn't begin the deployment until current connections = 0.

I've tried the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244218/automated-deployment-to-an-f5-load-balanced-environment) without any luck and gone down a few more rabbit holes that didn't get me what I  need.

Hoping someone has tried this more recently and had better luck than I am

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Found it.

https://devcentral.f5.com/questions/get-local-traffic-statistics-gt-nodes

`$ic = get-F5.iControl

$ic.LocalLBNodeAddress.get_statistics("NODE_IP") | %{$*.statistics.statistics | ? {$*.type -eq "STATISTIC_SERVER_SIDE_CURRENT_CONNECTIONS"} | %{$_.value.low} }`